# How do I Reference Entities from Other sqlx Files in a DataForm Workspace Before Deploying to Production?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt, dataform

In the DataForm workspace, I am currently developing and have not yet deployed (run) to the production environment. I want to reference entities (sqlx) from other sqlx files within the workspace. After verifying the connections and behavior among multiple sqlx files in the workspace, I want to deploy them all to the production environment at once. How can I achieve this?